# Translation for "Doing x is good for you"

Tags: translation, particle

If I translated "It is good for you to learn German", I would probably say

> Es ist gut für dich, Deutsch zu lernen.

But if let me translate "Learning German is good for you", I don't know the proper translation. Is it acceptable to say

> Lernend Deutsch ist gut für dich.

Answer (score 1):

The English ing-form can take a wide range of grammatical functions. One of those is being a noun, a function the German equivalent does not share. Thus your translation is wrong. How to get it correct? 
You need to find out what the German noun would be for "learning German". The simplest way would be

> Deutschlernen ist gut für dich.

However, this is not very good style, and there is no real consensus as to how to spell "Deutschlernen". So the phrasing basically doesn't work, and you'd use the first one instead.
A general answer is hard to give as it always comes down to how idiomatic the respective noun would be. However, using the zu-version is a safe bet, since we're talking about an activity and so phrasing it using a verb is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say (no native speaker):

> Deutsch zu lernen ist gut für dich.